# Problem in Creating Zip file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have requirement in my project with which when user select multiple file to download, we need to zip them and then make them to download. We have tested that the Struts2 action is listing all the file correctly and passing them to the UI. We've verified that the files are list on to UI correctly but when the blob statement executed, it made the zip file corrupted. 
Here is the my code snippet. 
Can anyone please help here?

Code:

```
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: data,
      type: "POST",
      async: true,
      success: function (data) {
        var binaryData = [];
        binaryData.push(data);
        var link=document.createElement('a');
        link.href =window.URL.createObjectURL(**new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/zip"**}));
        link.download = "User Reports Data Files.zip"
        link.click();
      },
      error: function (request, status, error) {
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Two answers for you:

1. I don't think you can reliably download **binary** data with jQuery's `ajax` function (but I could be mistaken). If you want to download binary, use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), which has support for reading the response as a BLOB built in.
2. It would be simpler to have a zero-height `iframe` on your page with `name="download-target"` and then have a `form target="download-target method="post"` and submit that instead of using ajax. Be sure the response includes a [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header, for instance:

   ```
   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="User Reports Data Files.zip"
   ```

#2 is simpler and lets the browser handle the download in its normal, thoroughly-tested way.

But here's a sketch of #1:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: data
})
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
    }
    return response.blob();
});
.then(blob => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = "User Reports Data Files.zip"
    link.style.display = "none";         // Firefox wants this
    document.body.appendChild(link);     // ""
    link.click();
    setTimeout(() => {                   // ""
        document.body.removeChild(link); // ""
    }, 10000);                           // ""
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report the error
});
```